# Role will not be installed as it already exists

Tags: security, packages, package-designer

I have created a sitecore security accounts package with an updated permissions on roles. When i try to install it, its says "Role will not be installed as it already exists".

Is that mean i can't override permissions on the roles using sitecore packages? is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `updated permissions on roles`?

Comment: For 'Global content' role i have given permission to "Delete" now, which does not exist before.

Comment: So you changed some item, not the role? You haven't changed inheritance of any role?

Comment: yes, in that case u suggesting to add the item in the package? to see the change?

Comment: Yes. you don't need to add role into to package. Role is already there. And it's only item security which is changed. Package that item only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you added/changed/removed item access for a role, you don't need to package that role and install it in the other environment. Role is not changed.

The only thing you have to do is to add the item which has new security rules to the package.

Find your item in Content Editor, make sure that `Standard Fields` checkbox is checked and scroll to the `Security` section to see how Sitecore stores your new item rights:

[image]

Here is a link to [Security Administrator´s
Cookbook](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/securityadministratorscookbook-usletter.pdf). It's for Sitecore 6 but the concepts haven't changed. It all works in the same way in Sitecore 8.x.

Comment: is there a way to just package permissions of the item, rather than whole item? as i don't want the whole item to be copied across to production.

Comment: No, Sitecore does not allow to create a Field-Level packages.